# C# Webdriver Page Object Framework Retrieve dynamic value from table

Tags: c#, object, selenium-webdriver, frameworks

I have adapted a Page Object Framework Program that is written in C# and uses Selenium Webdriver.

The following code finds the radio button with a premium of $750.00

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(//label[text()='$750.00'])")]
public IWebElement rb_500K_limit_500D_750_prem { get; set; }
```

However, the premium amount will change. Therefore, I would like to do the following:

1. Read in the value of the premium from the table (See HTML from
   web page below) Note the current value is $750.00 but this will
   change for different tests that are run.
2. Click the radio button that corresponds with the value that is
   retrieved

HTML

```
<td class="prem-col">
    <input id="rate-radio-145535" class="rate-radio radio form-element-left-radio" type="radio" name="rate_id" value="145535"><label for="rate-radio-145535" class="rate-label label-right">$750.00</label>
</td>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your post is incomplete, or you copied/pasted this from something else.  There is no HTML from web page below.

Comment: It was there but there is a bug where if you have a numbered list, text formatted as code below will not show up. I fixed it... waiting for the edit to be accepted.

Comment: I left my comment above and went to enter a bug on the buggy formatting and found out it's By Design. If you have code formatted text in or after a numbered list you have to indent it with 4 *additional* spaces. Just an FYI...

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? There may be other ways to do this.